# Convert tapply summary result to data frame

Tags: r

My code is:

```
Normality <- tapply(input$TotalAuthBdNet.USD., input$Country, summary)
```

The output displayed is:

```
$Albania
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.000e+00 1.066e+04 2.730e+04 3.403e+07 5.015e+04 2.720e+09 

$Angola
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   5405   15323   52522  486451  170000 4513196 

$`Antigua and Barbuda`
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  22622   22622   22622   22622   22622   22622       2 

$Argentina
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
      0   15814   45000  212800  193626 4080293      15
```

Country names are in rows and each country will have such statistic.  I want the output as:

```
Country   Min.        1st Qu.  Median    Mean     3rd Qu.      Max.    NA's 
Albania  0.000e+00 1.066e+04 2.730e+04 3.403e+07 5.015e+04 2.720e+09
Angola      5405   15323   52522  486451  170000 4513196
Argentina      0   15814   45000  212800  193626 4080293      15
```

The country name is a list identified from the file.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `rbind` would do.. E.g.

```
do.call(rbind, tapply(mpg$year, mpg$model, summary))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly call `aggregate` so you don't need the extra step:

```
aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris, summary)
#      Species Sepal.Length.Min. Sepal.Length.1st Qu. Sepal.Length.Median Sepal.Length.Mean Sepal.Length.3rd Qu. Sepal.Length.Max.
# 1     setosa             4.300                4.800               5.000             5.006                5.200             5.800
# 2 versicolor             4.900                5.600               5.900             5.936                6.300             7.000
# 3  virginica             4.900                6.225               6.500             6.588                6.900             7.900
```